# Transfer the script to C from Shell

Tags: c

I have a script that reads from a file, sorts and displays the data (Shell)

```
   #!/bin/awk
    sort -t ' ' -k 10 -r -n log.txt | head -n 10 | awk '{sum+=$10; array[NR,1]=$11; array[NR,2]=$10; next;} END {

      for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)

        printf "%3.0f'\.' %s \b '\-' %s \b '\-' %3.1f'\%' \n", i, array[i,1], array[i,2], array[i,2]/sum*100

     }'
```

Example script (Shell):

```
 1. "http://www.example.org/example/When/200x/2004/11/08/Yellow" - 1116675 - 50.5%
  2. "http://www.example.org/example/When/200x/2003/07/25/NotGaming" - 220810 - 10.0%
  3. "http://www.example.org/example/When/200x/2003/07/25/NotGaming" - 183618 - 8.3%
  4. "http://www.example.org/example/When/200x/2003/07/25/NotGaming" - 161648 - 7.3%
  5. "http://www.example.org/example/When/200x/2003/07/25/NotGaming" - 160646 - 7.3%
  6. "http://www.example.org/example/When/200x/2003/07/25/NotGaming" - 156241 - 7.1%
  7. "http://www.example.org/example/When/200x/2003/07/25/NotGaming" - 62006 - 2.8%
  8. "http://www.example.org/example/serif.css" - 52140 - 2.4%
  9. "http://www.example.org/example/serif.css" - 52140 - 2.4%
 10. "-" - 44877 - 2.0%
```

My task is to do the same only in C (*.с). 
I know how to read the file. Known grep function. I do not know how to replace awk function.

Comment: And where are you stuck? Or do you think someone will solve your problem for you?

Comment: I know how to read the file. Known grep. I do not know how to replace awk function.

Comment: Why do you want to do that in C? Why can't you use your script?

Comment: Because it my home work in university. I wite program in Shell. Next step POSIX and write in C.

Comment: To read the file you must first open the file with `fopen`. You will benefit if you learn to read the file one-line-at-a-time using either `getline` or `fgets` and then parsing the line using either character pointers or `sscanf`. You do not need to recode `awk`, you need to analyze what that particular `awk` **statement** does and then code that. Not difficult, just a number of moving parts. Compare `sort -t ' ' -k 10 -r -n log.txt | head -n 10` to the results piped to `awk` to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think of translating your shell script line by line into some C code, but think of designing & implementing a C program from scratch (having a functionality equivalent to your shell script).

I am guessing that you are targeting some Linux system, and I suppose that you know some [C programming](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

You might find useful the following C functions: [qsort(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) for sorting; [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or perhaps [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) to read a line. [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) & `free` for generic [C dynamic memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation); [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) & [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) (at least for crude error handling); [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) for parsing a previously read line (don't forget to use the returned item count); [regex(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html) for regexpr matching; [strstr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html) & [strchr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) to search inside strings; [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html), [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) (Linux or GNU [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) specific!), [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) to build strings.

If you want to do some HTTP client processing in C, consider using some HTTP client library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/); if you want an HTTP server library in C, consider [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/).

I also recommend reading [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

I assume that you are somehow familiar with C. If not, you might find easier to learn then use [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/) or [Python](http://python.org/) for such tasks.

BTW compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, learn how to use the `gdb` debugger & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: I now Learning POSIX.  Thanks for the tip. It should be a simple method, to do.

Comment: It might be simpler to learn Linux, and discover later the small difference between Linux and POSIX (which is a specification).